# pandas does not read a excel file fine after I've save a Datetime cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, openpyxl

I am reading a file with pandas read_excel

```
df0 = pd.read_excel(cfname,'Calendari', index_col=0, parse_cols='A:R',
            converters={'Categoria':str,'Fase':str, 'Grupo':str, 'Jornada':str,  
                               'Partido':str, 'IdPartido':str,'Leido':str})
df0.head()
```

The output is:

```
Linea Categoria Fase Grupo Jornada Partido IdPartido Leido Data                 Hora   
    2       CCM    1     1       1      -1       NaN    No Jornada 1            NaN  
    3       CCM    1     1       1       0       NaN    No Data                 Hora    
    4       CCM    1     1       1       1 CCM110101    No 2017-09-30 00:00:00  19:30:00  
    5       CCM    1     1       1       2 CCM110102    No 2017-09-30 00:00:00  17:45:00  
    6       CCM    1     1       1       3 CCM110103    No 2017-09-27 00:00:00  18:00:00
```

I write a new date with openpyxl: in line 6 I write 2017-10-01

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = cfname, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Calendari')
cell = ws['I6']
cell.value = datetime.strptime('01/10/2017', "%d/%m/%Y")
cell.number_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
wb.save(filename = cfname)
```

In Excel, the date seems well saved, with Date Format. But when I try to read the file again with pandas read_excel, the data has been change
**but the values for *Jornada Partido IdPartido* becomes NaN**

```
Linea Categoria Fase Grupo Jornada Partido IdPartido Leido Data                 Hora   
    2       CCM    1     1     NaN     NaN       NaN    No Jornada 1            NaN  
    3       CCM    1     1     NaN     NaN       NaN    No Data                 Hora    
    4       CCM    1     1     NaN     NaN       NaN    No 2017-09-30 00:00:00  19:30:00  
    5       CCM    1     1     NaN     NaN       NaN    No 2017-09-30 00:00:00  17:45:00  
    6       CCM    1     1     NaN     NaN       NaN    No 2017-10-01 00:00:00  18:00:00
```

I do not know why. I try with converters, without them, diferent date format, ...
Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your post for this line ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Calendari')cell = ws['I6']

Comment: The two outputs looks identical. Which column is causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already opened a file with openpyxl then you can use the builtin utilities for converting it to Pandas. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html

As the values have already been converted to Python objects the conversion Pandas is quick and reliable.

Comment: I read the file with Pandas, and it works. I have a for loop to go trough some rows. When it is needed, I`ve change the date of a Partido (match). But the next time I open the file with Pandas it loose the information of columns Jornada, Partido and IdPartido. They become NaN

Comment: Then don't read the file with Pandas. Use openpyxl for reading and writing the file and Pandas for any analysis or changing.

Answer (score 0):

I following doing tests. Ultimately I have discovered that if I open and save the excel file out of python (with Excel program), when I try to read the file again with pandas already does not give me the mistake.

I do not understand nothing. Something does not close fine with

```
wb.save(filename = cfname)
```

It will be because my Excel file is a macro xlxm? I open it with:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = cfname, keep_vba=True)
```